# Docker Selenium Configuration not working properly on default bridge

Tags: selenium, docker, docker-compose, selenium-grid

If I create a separate network then this commands work properly but on the default bridge not working. Commands are given below

```
docker run -d -p 4444:4444 --net bridge --name selenium-hub selenium/hub:3.14.0-beryllium

docker run -d --net bridge -e HUB_HOST=selenium-hub -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm selenium/node-chrome:3.14.0-beryllium
```

1. Why this is happened?

Another question I am using the Docker Compose for selenium docker

So I create the docker compose file as below

```
# To execute this docker-compose yml file use `docker-compose -f <file_name> up`
# Add the `-d` flag at the end for detached execution
version: "3.6"
services:
    selenium-hub:
      image: selenium/hub
      network_mode: bridge
      container_name: hub
      ports:
        - "4446:4444"
    firefox:
      image: selenium/node-firefox
      network_mode: bridge
      container_name: firefox-node
      ports:
        - "5557:5555"
        - "49339:5900"
      environment:
        - NODE_MAX_INSTANCES=5
        - NODE_MAX_SESSION=5
      links:
        - "selenium-hub:hub"
    chrome:
      image: selenium/node-chrome
      network_mode: bridge
      container_name: chrome-node
      ports:
        - "5556:5555"
        - "49338:5900"
      environment:
        - NODE_MAX_INSTANCES=5
        - NODE_MAX_SESSION=5
      links:
        - "selenium-hub:hub"
```

But here I faced the problem that If we want to scale up the node then port conflict will happen. I need to expose the node ports as well for debugging the selenium script on the node using VNC.

2. So is it possible to publish the port randomly from docker compose like -P option as we used from Docker run.
3. We mentioned Selenium Grid container name from Docker compose. Is it possible to mention the Node name even if we scale up the node it will be not conflicted with other custom containers.

Comment: Are you using docker tool box ?

Comment: @Ankur No, I am not using docker toolbox I am using normal docker on the Win10 machine